# How to count two field by year

Tags: mysql

I want to count two field by year

I try

```
SELECT YEAR(admit_date),COUNT(sub_case),COUNT(SK) 
FROM admit 
WHERE sub_case = "scase001" 
  AND SK = "rsk002"
GROUP BY YEAR(admit_date),sub_case,SK
```

But it not true

Table

[image]

Total

[image]

True

```
2014 1 0
2015 1 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a conditional aggregation instead like this:

```
SELECT 
  YEAR(admit_date) AS "admit_year",
  SUM(sub_case = 'scase001') AS "sub_case_count",
  SUM(SK = 'rsk002') AS "sk_count"
FROM admit
GROUP BY YEAR(admit_date)
```

The expression `sub_case = 'scase001'` will evaluate to 1 for all matching rows, and summing up the matches is the same as counting them. Using (or abusing) a boolean expression this way might not work in other SQL databases, but it does in MySQL (normally one would use a `case when ... then .. end` expression).

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the sub_case and SK column from the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT YEAR(admit_date),COUNT(sub_case),SUM(CASE WHEN SK="rsk002" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM admit 
WHERE sub_case = "scase001" 
GROUP BY YEAR(admit_date)
```